# XSLT replace null element and attribute value

Tags: xslt, attributes, replace, null, element

In the below XSLT I'm checking the following

1. If element is null then replace then replace it with the value of another element.
2. If attribute of that element is null then replace it with constant value.

1 is working, however 2 is not.

For 2 I have tried two things:

First, using the `xsl:if` condition didn't work.
It is adding a new node with the same node name instead of inserting a value to the attribute.

Second I have tried to use the template. That didn't work either.
It is completely eliminating the node and adding the attribute to the parent with the value.

Also, is it possible to do it differently or a better way.

**XSLT**

```
  <xsl:template match="//ns0:Cedent/ns0:Party/ns0:Id">
    <xsl:if test="//ns0:Cedent/ns0:Party/ns0:Id = ''">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="//ns0:Broker/ns0:Party/ns0:Id"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
    <!--<xsl:if test="//ns0:Cedent/ns0:Party/ns0:Id[@Agency = '']">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="Agency">Legacy</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="'Legacy'"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>-->
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//ns0:Cedent/ns0:Party/ns0:Id[@Agency = '']">
    <xsl:attribute name="Agency">Legacy</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
```

**input**

```
<ns0:Testing>
  <ns0:Cedent>
    <ns0:Party>
      <ns0:Id Agency=""></ns0:Id>
      <ns0:Name>Canada</ns0:Name>
    </ns0:Party>
  </ns0:Cedent>
  <ns0:Broker>
    <ns0:Party>
      <ns0:Id Agency="Legacy">292320710</ns0:Id>
      <ns0:Name>Spain</ns0:Name>
    </ns0:Party>
  </ns0:Broker>
</ns0:Testing>
```

**output**

```
<ns0:Testing>
    <ns0:Cedent>
      <ns0:Party>
        <ns0:Id Agency="Legacy">292320710</ns0:Id>
        <ns0:Name>Canada</ns0:Name>
      </ns0:Party>
    </ns0:Cedent>
</ns0:Testing>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:ns0="some_namespace_uri"
>
  <xsl:output indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ns0:Cedent/ns0:Party/ns0:Id[. = '']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="
        ../../following-sibling::ns0:Broker[1]/ns0:Party/ns0:Id/node()
      " />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ns0:Cedent/ns0:Party/ns0:Id/@Agency[. = '']">
    <xsl:attribute name="Agency">Legacy</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Gives you

```
<Testing xmlns="some_namespace_uri">
  <Cedent>
    <Party>
      <Id Agency="Legacy">292320710</Id>
      <Name>Canada</Name>
    </Party>
  </Cedent>
  <Broker>
    <Party>
      <Id Agency="Legacy">292320710</Id>
      <Name>Spain</Name>
    </Party>
  </Broker>
</Testing>
```

Notes:

- if you don't want the `<Broker>` element in the output at all, add an empty template:

  ```
  <xsl:template match="ns0:Broker" />
  ```
- Match expressions in templates do not need to start at the root node.
- Stylesheets whose job it is to copy the input with only a few changes, like this one, should always start with the identity template.